# Release management server succeeds manual, but fails automated

Tags: visual-studio-2013, release, release-management, ms-release-management

I'm trying to configure release management server to deploy to out test server when a specific build configuration on TFS succeeds. Now I have a build definition which runs fine, I use the build process template 'ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12.xaml'.

The 'Release Template' in Release Management Server (RMS) is set to trigger on build.

Now when I set the 'Release Build' property in the Release category to 'False', the build runs fine. Then when I go the Release Management Client and create a release, everything goes fine and my project (a WebAPI) is succesfully published to our testserver.

As soon as I set the 'Release build' property to true (in the build definition) and queue a new build, the build fails.

I receive the following error :

> Exception Message: The directory name is invalid (type Win32Exception)
>   Exception Stack Trace:  Server stack trace:     at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.InvokeProcess.ProcessWrapper.Start()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.InvokeProcess.InvokeProcessInternal.RunCommand(AsyncState
>   state)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message
>   reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed,
>   MessageData& msgData)    at System.Func`2.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity`1.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)

The build template includes a xcopy step which may cause the "The directory name is invalid", but I don't understand why the process works manually, but not automated.

Any suggestions in the right direction are very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a RM Client install on the build agent machine.

Comment: Totally fixed my problem, thanks! Cannot vote up because lack of reputation.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the release template can 'lose' its connection in to the build definition. To check this open the release template and use the Properties link to re-establish the connection to the build definition. In case it helps I have a soup to nuts blog post series on configuring all this - index page [here](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-with-tfs/).

Comment: That is clearly not the problem here. It's a problem on the build server, probably with finding the RM client.